# Xcode6 beta 5 takes all empty memory, Swift

Tags: swift

I use Xcode6  beta 5

I try to get milliseconds from beginning of the day.

```
var date:NSDate = NSDate()
var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(
    NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
var hour = components.hour
var minute = components.minute
var seconds = components.second
```

So I got hours. minutes and seconds and do simple calculation:

```
var milli:UInt64 = hour*60*60*1000 + minute*60*1000 + seconds*1000
```

or

```
var milli:Double = hour*60*60*1000 + minute*60*1000 + seconds*1000
```

Xcode eats all my memory > 7G

I know that its Beta, I'm not iOS programmer, is this any problem in my code?

**[EDIT]**

- **happens in playground and in swift file after Ctrl+S**
- no loops

Thanks,

Comment: First, don't do that, use `NSDateComponents`. Secondly, iOS app or playground. 3. is there a loop or any kind in your program?

Comment: @Zaph I need calculate milliseconds from start of the day. How `NSDateComponents` might help me? please see my edit

Comment: You have three date components to combine. Also not all minutes have 60 seconds (yeah that is rare). In general it is best to leave time and calendar calculations to the APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I know that its Beta" Yuuup!
Errors from bad code are harder to test for. I'd bet the error is in automatic type conversion. At least we know it is not a `goto fail` code error. ;-)

Xcode6 beta 5 is buggy with this code, the compile does not complete and Xcode gees using more and more memory.

The program is flawed because different types are being used.

Example that works:

```
let seconds:UInt64 = 23
let minute:UInt64 = 12
let hour:UInt64 = 8
var milli:UInt64 = hour*60*60*1000 + minute*60*1000 + seconds*1000
println("milli: \(milli)") // milli: 29543000
```

Comment: So as workaround I need cast all variables to one type?

Comment: Yes. Swift expects all the correct types. This does seem to have been relaxed somewhat deice Beta1.

Comment: I'll except this answer because it works, thanks. Do you know what is better in this case: Double or UInt64?

Comment: I would go with int since there are no fractional seconds.